# iPhone - How to set up not requiring passcode if recently closed

Tags: iphone, ios, unlock, security

I have an iPhone with iOS 8. Is there a way to setup my phone where it doesn't require a passcode to unlock if it has been closed in the last 5 (or some amount) minutes?

I know that my computer has a 15min feature.

Thanks

Comment: Re: the 2 existing answers - my 5S doesn't have 'Passcode Lock'. It does have Auto Lock. However, whatever I set it to, if I 'sleep' the phone with the top button, it immediately requires my ID if I wake it again. My partner's 5 doesn't, hers stays unlocked. Maybe it's the fingerprint ID that makes the difference?

Comment: @Tetsujin see if my answer below explains your experience.

Comment: @Tyson Ah, so it **is** the fingerprint ID that does it. We both use exchange for email, but not 'corporate' it's my own domain & I don't have the phones policy-locked, so the difference is the touchID. tbh, with the touchID, it's actually faster than swiping & entering a code, but I was always puzzled by the difference in behaviour.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't use 'corporate' exchange either, I have a personal office365 account, and it does not expose the setting discussed in the linked thread.  However! if I delete my exchange email account I do get more options.  I agree tho that with touchid it makes it irrelevant, I did all the discovery for this a long time ago before I was really used to touchid being so easy.

Comment: @Tyson I have what is technically a business account, but it's actually just because my ISP has kept upgrading me since 2001 so I'm very nicely grandfathered these days ;) It cleared up my puzzle anyway, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the setting you are looking for is `Settings` > `Touch ID and Passcode` > `Require Passcode`.

It should be noted that using a Microsoft Exchange account in email can effect the options available here.  For example the only option on my phone is "immediately".  [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5385567) is how i finally learned why I only have the option "immediately".

Comment: While this is correct. I now see that there is no solution to my challenge. I wish I could delay it and still you the fingerprint

Comment: The setting is not at that place for iphone 5c. I have not discovered where it is yet.

Comment: @javadba "5c" is not what is relevant, if the setting is not there then you must have a very old iOS version, what is you iOS version?

Comment: 9.2.1. Uploaded within past 24 hours.

Comment: It's still on that screen, about halfway down.   It follows change passcode link and is before the voice dial selection.

Comment: @Mhsmith21: This is possible with a jailbreak and the tweak "Mesalation" from Cydia (http://cydia.saurik.com/package/jp.r-plus.mesalation).

Answer (score 6):

You have to disable Touch ID for "iPhone Unlock" on newer iOS devices in order to set a time to lock your phone.  In Settings > Touch ID & Passcode, disable (toggle off) Touch ID for iPhone Unlock.  Once toggled off, you can then change the time to require passcode by accessing the "Require Passcode" option.

Basically it sets to "immediately" only with Touch ID enabled for unlocking your phone.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the `Settings` App and navigate to `General` –> `Passcode Lock`.
2. To set the passcode lock delay, locate the button where you see `Require Passcod`e. By default you will see “Immediately” next to `Require Passcode`. This means that as soon as your device locks, your passcode will be enabled. If you want to delay this, tap on the button and select After 1 minute, After 5 minutes, or After 15 minutes. When you select any of these three time intervals, your device will not require you to re-enter your passcode for the relative time you selected.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean can be found under settings> general. There's a function called, I think, Automatic Lock.

You can automatically lock your iphone after:

- 1 minute
- 2 minutes
- 3 minutes
- 4 minutes
- 5 minutes
- Never

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override the requirement to use a passcode - say if Microsoft exchange is installed and the requirement for a passcode is set server-side; and if your phone is JB'd then you can install cydia then activator then an app called bypass which will run within activator.  both activator and bypass are located on the bigboss repo that comes preinstalled in cydia.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I've found with my 6s, running iOS 9.3.2, if you have the option "Use Touch ID for:" and you have "iPhone Unlock" turned on then the option "Require Passcide" will be automatically limited to "immediately" as well as selected & unchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

6s 
10.1.1
turned off Touch ID 
Allowed delayed lock options

Comment: Huh?  Is there an answer here?